# /usr/bin/mingw32-cmake: line 84: fg: no job control (Midori cross-compiling error)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, fedora, vala

I'm trying to compile [Midori Web Browser](http://midori-browser.org) for Windows on Fedora 22. For that purpose I'm following [this tutorial](http://midori-browser.org/contribute/#for_linux_developers).

I installed these dependencies except faenza-icon-theme:

```
yum install gcc vala intltool
yum install libsoup-devel webkitgtk3-devel sqlite-devel
yum install mingw{32,64}-webkitgtk3 mingw{32,64}-glib-networking mingw{32,64}-gdb mingw{32,64}-gstreamer-plugins-good
yum install faenza-icon-theme p7zip mingw32-nsis greybird-gtk3-theme
```

Later I installed faenzai-icon-theme via using a [third party rpm](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/30430169/dir/fedora_22/com/faenza-icon-theme-1.3-1.1.noarch.rpm.html).

I downloaded source:

```
bzr branch lp:midori
cd midori
mkdir _mingw32
cd _mingw32
```

But at this step:

```
mingw32-cmake .. -DUSE_ZEITGEIST=0 -DUSE_GTK3=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=0
```

I'm getting an error:

```
/usr/bin/mingw32-cmake: line 84: fg: no job control
```

I don't know how to solve this problem and the meaning of this error. I made a research on internet but nothing came up.

Comment: It means that a shell script is trying to run a program in the background, but the shell doesn't support doing that. Non-interactive shells (those running scripts) are not supposed to allow this by default, but some shells do. So, this script might work with another shell as `/bin/sh`. This is a bug in that script.

Comment: I tried: `bash mingw32-cmake .. -DUSE_ZEITGEIST=0 -DUSE_GTK3=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=0` Same error. I don't understand you clearly please help me.

Comment: @apmasell Are telling me that I have to run this command in a subshell?

Comment: No. I'm saying there's an error in the script. It should probably enable job control with `set -m`.

Comment: @apmasell What do you mean with `set -m`. Could you post an answer with a brief explanation, please?

Comment: This is a bug in `mingw32-cmake`. You should report it to the upstream developers.

Comment: @apmasell hmm OK then, thank you.

Comment: @mertyildiran I have a similar error with mingw32-meson. Did you open a bug? Did you solve it in the end. Very curious error :)

Comment: @mertyildiran hmm indeed, the answer 1 helps. I didn't install correctly meson. I wonder if we could improve the error message to make this more obvious...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FWIW: I had the same error message trying to build a project of mine. It went away after

```
yum install cmake
```

Both `mingw32-cmake` and `mingw64-cmake` need `cmake` to function. (Actually, make that `dnf install cmake` nowadays.)